# Rails / Stripe - missing template error in bookings controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm building an events app using Rails and I'm attempting to create code which first checks that spaces are available when a user tries to book and, if so, then takes them through to book the event.
I've hit the following error when trying to make a booking -

Missing template bookings/create

```
def find(*args)
  find_all(*args).first || raise(MissingTemplate.new(self, *args))
end

def find_all(path, prefixes = [], *args)
```

I'm not sure this has anything to do with the over booking situation as there should be spaces available.It's more to do with the Stripe code, I think. Here's the relevant code -

bookings_controller.rb

```
  class BookingsController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    # booking form
    # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
    @booking = @event.bookings.new
    # which person is booking the event?
    @booking.user = current_user
    #@booking.quantity = @booking.quantity
    #@total_amount = @booking_quantity.to_f * @event_price.to_f

end

def create
    # actually process the booking
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user
    #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f

    Booking.transaction do
        @booking.save!
        @event.reload
        if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
            flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
        else
            if @booking.save

                # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
                # #{} == puts a variable into a string
                Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @event.price_pennies, currency: "gbp",
                    card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")

                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_path(@event)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end

            if @event.is_free?

                @booking.save!
                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_path(@event)
            end

        end 
    end


end


#def total_amount
    #@total_amount = @booking.quantity * @event.price
#end

private

def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
end



end
```

new.html.erb (bookings) -

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Confirm Your Booking</h2>
        </div>

            <div class="panel-body">    

                <p>Total Amount<%= @event.price %></p>
                <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>





                 <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                      <span>Card Number</span>
                      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <label>
                  <span>CVC</span>
                  <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
                    </label>
                    <span> / </span>
                    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">    

               <%= form.button :submit %>


            </div> 

<% end %>
<% end %>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>');
  var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#new_booking');

    if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="booking[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  };

  // jQuery(function($)  { - changed to the line below
  $(document).on("ready page:load", function () {

    $('#new_booking').submit(function(event) {
      var $form = $(this);

      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

      Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

      // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not save the booking and then check for count. Instead, you can this.

```
    def create
    # actually process the booking
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user
    #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f

    Booking.transaction do
        if @event.bookings.count == @event.number_of_spaces
            flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
        else
            if @booking.save

                # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
                # #{} == puts a variable into a string
                Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @event.price_pennies, currency: "gbp",
                    card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")

                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_path(@event)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end

            if @event.is_free?

                @booking.save!
                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_path(@event)
            end

        end 
    end


end
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this previously but what I find is that the app takes me through the Stripe payment process THEN tells me the event is fully booked. I need it to tell me the event is fully booked before it tries to take my money.

Comment: Also, I'm still getting same error. This hasn't worked.